# Codeception acceptance tests fail with LogicException: The page history is empty

Tags: soap, codeception, acceptance-testing

I am preparing acceptance tests for my SOAP API methods. I've already made two of them and if I launch each of them separately, they pass without any problems. But if I call them together using `codecept run acceptance`, second always fails with `[LogicException] The page history is empty` on `$I->see();` method. Why is it so?

I'm using codeception v2.0.11 and my suit is:

```
class_name: AcceptanceSOAPTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser
        - SOAP
        - ApiHelper
    config:
        PhpBrowser:
            url: http://localhost/
        SOAP:
            endpoint: http://localhost/soap/
            schema: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
```